# scrapy-redis re-crawl the url that one machine has already crawled

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, distributed

I have written a distributed spider using `scrapy-redis.`
At first, everything seemed fine.

The setting file:

```
SCHEDULER = "scrapy_redis.scheduler.Scheduler"
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = "scrapy_redis.dupefilter.RFPDupeFilter"
SCHEDULER_QUEUE_CLASS = 'scrapy_redis.queue.SpiderPriorityQueue'
```

However, after crawling all the URLs, one spider closed, but another didn't - and began to re-crawl the URLs that were already crawled.

Can anyone help me, and explain why?

Comment: Bidal, we may be able to help if you showed us a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem! The spider do not closed normally due to wrong parameters settings using "def close_spider(self, spider):" function.